# Understanding the character message ordering sent from TranslateMessage()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, event-handling

The following is a classic message loop. The [TranslateMessage(const MSG*)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/ms644955(v=vs.85).aspx), as MSDN says, does translate the virtual-key message(`WM_KEYDOWN`) into character message(`WM_CHAR`). Then it will post this just translated `WM_CHAR` message into the thread message queue.

AFAIK the message queue should be a **FIFO** structure, and the message `WM_CHAR` will be sent at the end of queue when `TranslateMessage` returns. I make a experiment that pressing multiple keys down at the same time, e.g. 'a', 's', and 'd'. And I put a `sleep(1000)` to make these 3 `WM_KEYDOWN` messages to be queued first in the message queue before invoked `TranslateMessage()` .

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    Sleep(1000) // make message queue receives all the WM_KEYDOWN before Translated                     
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     print_the_message(uMsg, wParam);
}
```

I expect the ordering should be

- WM_KEYDOWN('a')
- WM_KEYDOWN('s')
- WM_KEYDOWN('f')
- /* Queued before sleep wake */
- WM_CHAR('a')
- WM_CHAR('s')
- WM_CHAR('f')

But print_the_message actually shows this ordering

- WM_KEYDOWN('a')
- WM_CHAR('a')
- WM_KEYDOWN('s')
- WM_CHAR('s')
- WM_KEYDOWN('f')
- WM_CHAR('f')

Does the character message `WM_CHAR` created by `TranslateMessage` have special priority or handling to make it can follow the previous `WM_KEYDOWN` message and cut in the queue?

Comment: The term "queue" in message queue is only an abstraction, helpful to mentally model its behavior.  It does not match the behavior of a FIFO queue all that well in practice.  As you found out.  Pretty important that it works this way of course, imagine what would happen if the WM_KEYDOWN messages are for the Shift or Control key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955.aspx) says, with my emphasis:

> The character messages are posted to the calling thread's message queue, to be read the **next time** the thread calls the GetMessage or PeekMessage function.

This matches the observed behaviour.

Comment: So I can say the messages are `inserted` at the front of the queue?

Comment: That's what you observe, and what is documented